# Issues accessing Sinatra app in Docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra

I have a sinatra API server that I can run successfully run locally on port 9292 which I want to run in a container.

I create a Dockerfile with the following:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs --no-install-recommends && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD . /myapp
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE 9292
CMD bundle exec rackup config.ru
```

After building the image, I run the following command to spin up the container: `docker run -it -p 9292:9292 --rm api-server`

I am confirmed that the app is up and running and am provided additional details:

`Listening on localhost:9292, CTRL+C to stop`

Despite this, I am unable to return any results from the server. Any thoughts as to why I can't access the container? I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 with Docker 1.9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by specifying the host as 0.0.0.0 on my thin server. My Dockerfile command now reads as such: `CMD bundle exec rackup -o 0.0.0.0 -p 9292 config.ru`